# Slide Toggle goes upward, scrolling affects the position of sidebar

Tags: sticky

Im having a problem  in how im going to push it upward when it toggles down heres the code

`$("#inquire_button").click(function(){
         function formfocus() {
              document.getElementById('clientName').focus();
           }
           window.onload = formfocus;
        $("#pPage_mainDivRight_inquireDivTop").fadeOut(function(){
            $("#pPage_mainDivRight_inquireDivBottom").stop().slideToggle("slow");
            if($(document).scrollTop()<=284){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: "284px"
                },1000);
            }
            if($(document).scrollTop()>=900){
                /*$(".pPage_mainDivRight_headerDiv3").css({"position":"fixed","top":"123px"});*/
                $(".pPage_mainDivRight_headerDiv3").stop().animate({"top":"-10px"}, "slow");
            }
        });
    });`

Here's the code for scrolling

`$(document).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop()>=265){
            $(".pPage_mainDivRight_headerDiv3").css({"position":"fixed","top":"123px"});
        }
        if($(this).scrollTop()<=305){
            $(".pPage_mainDivRight_headerDiv3").css({"position":"static","top":"123px"});
        }
     });`

and after i toggle it, if i scrolled it up the position of the sidebar toggle gets destroyed.

heres the preview when i toggled it up
![1]: https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/11053/EM4rLcpMJwdLm9CtSOkwZiiPGm53bnxU/

and when i scrolled it the position destroyed
![2]: https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/11054/QTin2OKMMF60OGgS5x9WzBfTDGcVzpQn/

Comment: Do you have a preview?

Comment: @Finn the preview is already indicated above thank you